# can't parse XML with XElement properly

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm having troubling squaring away the parsing of NASA RSS feeds. I've researched all I can and there seems to be one part I'm missing, or for all I know right now it might be more. But I'm only getting one error in VS and I've tried everything. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
private void UpdateFeedList(string feedXML)
    {


        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(feedXML);
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
        XElement XDocument = XElement.Load(xmlReader);

        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            listBox.ItemsSource = XDocument.Items;
        });
    }
```

The error I'm currently getting in VS is in the last line '.items' . VS is telling me that XElement does not contain a definition for Items.

Answer (score 0):

> VS is telling me that XElement does not contain a definition for Items.

And it's absolutely right - see [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx). It's not clear what you *expected* it to do, but you need to extract the relevant information from the `XElement`, e.g.

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    listBox.ItemsSource = XDocument.Elements("SomeElementName");
});
```

As an aside, using a variable name of `XDocument` is bad enough, but when that's not even the type of the variable, it's a *horrible* idea. It's like declaring:

```
int String = 10; // Just don't do it!
```

Additionally, your first three lines can be vastly simplified:

```
XElement element = XElement.Parse(feedXml);
```

But you really need to think about what you want the collection of items to actually be... perhaps you want to transform the feed into a collection of objects of some type you create yourself?